# Checked box triggers clone()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to trigger clone() when user checks off a box.

I did my homework and had a look how the correct syntax looks like (source: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp)

Problem is of course I needed to modify the code to make it serve to my purpose and here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#copyAddress").change(function() {
        $(this).is(":checked") ? $("#userAddress").clone(true).appendTo("#motherAddress");
    });
});
```

But it isn't working. Already checked if ids are really ids and not classes.

Comment: Define "isn't working" (what errors do you get, what is, or isn't happening,...) and post a [mcve] (including the HTML)

Comment: You're sure you don't just want to set the same value in two inputs, which seems like a more normal thing to do when someone checks a checkbox to copy an adress?

Comment: How many "mother addresses" do you intend to have? What if user toggles the checkbox several times? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: A conditional ternary operator requires three components, the assessment and a 'truthy' and 'falsey,' you're missing one, which should have generated an error. Have you looked at your console?

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply try this, it's almost the same thing but it might work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#copyAddress").change(function() {
           if($(this).is(":checked")) {
               $("#userAddress").clone(true).appendTo("#motherAddress");
           }
        });
    });
```

*Always look for the errors in the console.*

Answer (score 0):

**Elements must have an unique Id.**

When you clone an element which has an id, this must be first removed and then replaced with a new unique id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#copyAddress").change(function() {
        if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
             theId = getRandomArbitrary(100, 1000);
            $("#userAddress").clone().removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'userAddress'+theId ).appendTo("#motherAddress");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "theId = getRandomArbitrary(100, 1000);"  why you're assigning random number between 100 and 1000 to the variable ? What's the meaning behind this ?

Comment: Well I'm not getting any errors in console but it just not doing anything at all. And I suspect because this bit of code doesn't work the first bit of code won't run either. Because the first bit runs just fine but as soon as I take off the commenting marks it stops run. So I've tried all the suggestions here but sadly nothing works for me.

Comment: I only have made a correction while you are cloning your element, and pointed out that yuo need to add a new Id to the cloned element. That is necessary because the Id must be unique. I can not see what `#copyAddress` is because you are not posting any `html` so it is possible that the code inside this statement it doen't run at all.

Comment: @MarkAlexa I am not assigning something to a variable. I am just giving a new Id to the cloned element as you can see here: `userAddress'+theId`. As stated you may not have elements with the same id. If you clone this element ` $("#userAddress").clone()` then you will have two elements with this id.